# Write department number and department total in empty rows

Tags: vba, excel

i have file where i want to insert three rows when the value of Column B changes, and then I want to write "Department Total:" at first blank rows which i have inserted and want to concatenate ("Department ",$B5,"#") in third blank row.
I want to do this for every set of blank rows in data.
i am able to this for concatenate part for third row. But Not able to write "Department Total:" in first blank row of every set

i have used this code to insert rows when the value of Column B changes:-

```
Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim WorkRng As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    xTitleId = "Enter the Range"
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = WorkRng.Rows.Count To 2 Step -1
        If WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
            WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Insert
            Range("A" & i).Value = "=CONCAT(""Department "",R[1]C[1],""#"")"
            WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Insert
            WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).EntireRow.Insert
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

but i am not able code for writing above mentioned details in those empty rows.
[image: looks like this before applying the code]

[image: Here is snippet of the excel file, like that i want to do]

Can anyone have solution for this??

Comment: Note: Never ever use `On Error Resume Next` without proper error handling. This line just hides error messages but the errors still occur! You just cannot see them, therefore you are just blind! You can not debug/fix a code with that properly. Remove it completely or implement an error handling instead. Then run it again and see if you get any errors.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have removed that line. I am not getting any error. Please suggest my question also, if you have any idea @Pᴇʜ

Comment: It's very unclear to me what you are trying to do and what your actual question is. Can you give a better example eg. how looks your data before applying the script and what would you expect to look it afterwards (so we can see the difference)? Also please explain what range you would select when your script ask for it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ i have added the image before running the code. as you can see in image 1:- A2 and A4 are blank similarly A11 and A13 are also blank. Now in image 2:- you can see that A2 and A11 have value of department total: and A4 and A13 have department number.

Comment: i select the all data i have in that sheet. just like Ctrl+shift+end @Pᴇʜ

Comment: Are you sure your first screenshot is correct? Are there already empty lines BEFORE you run the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably something like that you were looking for. It's all about counting rows correctly, and you can insert 3 lines at once.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub InsertRowsAtValueChange()
    Dim xTitleId As String
    xTitleId = "Enter the Range"

    Dim WorkRng As Range
    Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
    Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim LastDepartmentRow As Long
    LastDepartmentRow = (WorkRng.Rows.Count + WorkRng.Row - 1)

    Dim i As Long
    For i = LastDepartmentRow To 2 Step -1
        If WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Value <> WorkRng.Cells(i - 1, 2).Value Then
            WorkRng.Cells(i, 2).Resize(RowSize:=3).EntireRow.Insert 'add 3 empty rows

            'write subtotal below
            Range("A" & LastDepartmentRow + 4).Value = "Department Total:"
            Range("C" & LastDepartmentRow + 4).Value = "=SUM(C" & i + 3 & ":C" & LastDepartmentRow + 3 & ")"
            Rows(LastDepartmentRow + 4).Font.Bold = True

            'write headline above
            Range("A" & i + 2).Value = "=CONCATENATE(""Department "",R[1]C[1],""#"")"
            Rows(i + 2).Font.Bold = True

            LastDepartmentRow = i - 1 'remember last subtotal department data row
        End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```